# getting multiple node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I got problem with my app that i develop using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).
I want to get data from firebase and compare it with another data from firebase and show it in a listview. 
The data that i want, is the string in the follow image.

[image: image of firebase]

The problem here is, *I dont know how to get multiple string from the database.*

**This is the code that i having been trying:**

```
public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference applydatabase;

String app;
String applied;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    app = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");

    applydatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Apply").child(app).child("Applyid");
    applydatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            applied = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get the child nodes and loop over them.

```
applydatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Apply").child(app).child("Applyid");
applydatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String first = null, second = null;
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (first == null) {
                first = child.getValue(String.class);
            } else if (second == null)
                second = child.getValue(String.class);
            }
        }
        // TODO: compare first and second
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok..i will try this later. But what should i do if there is more data to be added under applyid.is this solution still valid? And i need to use the data that i get from firebase for another method.